# How to find a message author's highest role?

Tags: discord.js

I would like to know how to get message author's highest role for my commands.
But whatever I do its always 
A) undenfined or
B) Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Its always one of these.
I looked on the documentation of discord.js and for them its easier. So I would need help.
I tried to search here but there was only one result that isnt working for me too.
My code that I try is:

```
    var mod = message.author;
    let rank = mod.highestRole.name;
    var offence = message.content.slice(28);
    if(!offence){
      message.reply("Please put a reason for warning")
      return;
    }
    var emb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Warn")
    .addField("Staff:", mod.username)
    .addField("Staff's ID:", mod.id)
    .addField("Staff's rank:", rank)
    .addField("Offender's username:", user.username)
    .addField("Offender's ID:", user.id)
    .addField("Offence:", offence)
    .setColor("RED");
```

I would love to get it working and it would make my life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

since discord.js v12 `highestRole` property of `GuildMember` was removed so you need to replace `highestRole` with [`roles.highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=highest)

Comment: Woa I looked on docs and its just like highestRole so Im confused by it lol thanks.

Comment: yes, that's mentioned on the v11 version of the docs, not the stable (v12 atm) version of the docs

Comment: Now Im getting: ```TypeError: Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor``` Im new to 12.1.1 and in docks its referred as MessageEmbed but that doesn't work too

Comment: That's another thing that changed in v12, it's `MessageEmbed` instead of `RichEmbed` now. Please review all the changes from v11 to v12 here: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html  and please use the `stable` version of docs here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome